# Show that every graph $G$ has a path of length $\delta(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

A path in a graph is a subgraph isomorphic to $P_n$, for some $n$. The length of a path is its number of edges. Prove that every graph $G$ has a path of length $\delta(G)$, where $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$.

Comment: Also, I think it's impolite to disregard suggestions on how to improve your question (such as those [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128459/)).

Answer (score 6):

Let $P$ be the longest path in $G$ from $v_0$ to $v_k$. As min degree is $\delta(G)$, this path contains every neighbor of $v_k$ are on this path and if it is not like this, then let us assume that there is a vertex $v_j$ neighbor of $v_k$ not in the path. then add this to the given path. and thus we get a path of longer length than $P$. A contradiction

Comment: I wish people wouldn't answer questions, when the person asking the question has put in no effort beyond copying the question out of a problem set.

Answer (score 5):

I hope its a simple graph. 
Let $P$ be the maximal path in the graph $G$. On the contrary assume $|P|\le\delta(G)$.

Suppose $v\in V(P)$ be an endpoint in the path. As $v$ is adjacent to $\delta(G)$ vertices.
All of its neighbours can't be in the path $P$. But then its contradicts the fact that its the maximal path.

Hence $|P|\ge\delta(G)+1$.

Comment: I think you need to choose $v$ to be the end vertex of the path.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it.

Comment: I wish people wouldn't answer questions, when the person asking the question has put in no effort beyond copying the question out of a problem set.